# AngularJS - wrong input validation status

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have an input and on `ng-change` i pass the `Form.input` in a function so i can do some stuff based on the inputs status (errors, valid/invalid...). But here is the weird thing: 
When i log the input i passed, i see in the console output that `input.$valid = false` which is the correct value. But when i log `input.$valid` itself i get that it is true which is false! Why is this happening??? When i try to parse `input.$valid` i get wrong value and i cannot do calculations based on that.

Here is the input:

```
<input ng-model="..."
       type="radio"
       name="input"
       ng-value={{v}}
       ng-disabled="field.readonly"
       ng-required="field.required"
       ng-init="test(Form.input)"
       ng-change="test(Form.input)">
```

And here is the test function:

```
$scope.test = function (object) {
    console.log(object);
    console.log(object.$valid);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
};
```

and here is the log output:

```
// console.log(object);
c {$viewValue: NaN, $modelValue: NaN, $parsers: Array[1], $formatters: Array[1], $viewChangeListeners: Array[1]…}
$dirty: false
$error: Object
$formatters: Array[1]
$invalid: true
$isEmpty: function (a){return F(a)||""===a||null===a||a!==a}
$modelValue: undefined
$name: "input"
$parsers: Array[1]
$pristine: true
$render: function (){c[0].checked=d.value==e.$viewValue}
$setPristine: function (){this.$dirty=!1;this.$pristine=!0;g.removeClass(e,yb);g.addClass(e,Pa)}
$setValidity: function (a,c){p[a]!==!c&&(c?(p[a]&&n--,n||(k(!0),this.$valid=!0,this.$invalid=!1)):(k(!1),this.$invalid=!0,this.$valid=!1,n++),p[a]=!c,k(c,a),l.$setValidity(a,c,this))}
$setViewValue: function (d){this.$viewValue=d;this.$pristine&&(this.$dirty=!0,this.$pristine=!1,g.removeClass(e,Pa),g.addClass(e,yb),l.$setDirty());r(this.$parsers,function(a){d=a(d)});this.$modelValue!==
$valid: false
$viewChangeListeners: Array[1]
$viewValue: undefined
__proto__: Object


// console.log(object);
true 


// console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
{"$viewValue":null,"$modelValue":null,"$parsers":[null],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[null],"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$name":"input","$error":{}}
```

---

**UPDATE**: I think i might have found something. When i do:

```
<input ...
       ng-init="{{test(Form.input)}}"
       ng-change="{{test(Form.input)}}">
```

instead of

```
<input ...
       ng-init="test(Form.input)"
       ng-change="test(Form.input)">
```

i get the correct result, but i also get an error in console:

```
Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error: Token 'test' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

Comment: Are you using functions in `ng-init` and `ng-change` just for testing purposes?

Comment: @Malkus no. i want to execute some other code depending on `Form.input.$valid` being true/false. But i need to make sure everything is working correctly so i use `test()` forn now.

Comment: Have you tried using `$watch` it to display the data and call your function it would be more effective.

Comment: yes but the problem is that when i try to *parse* `Form.input.$valid` i get the wrong value.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that there's nothing wrong with your code, it's just the way you are reading the console output.

By doing `console.log(object)` you are "printing" the JavaScript representation of the object. It's like if you were looking directly to the object's reference. This means that if the object is changed afterwards, you will see those changes as well. Think in it like the realtime representation of the object.

On the other logs (`console.log(object.$valid);` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(object));`) that doesn't happen because you are just printing strings/booleans, no object representations.

If you want to check the real object's content, stick to the:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: No, `console.log(JSON.stringify(object));` contains the wrong value. The input is invalid and it shows that is valid. when i put `{{Form.input.$valid}}` inside the HTML (view) i also see that the input is invalid. The problem shows up ONLY when i parse the input in javascript. It must have something to do with $valid. I think it needs to be evaluated by Angular in order to get the correct value. That's why it works when i do `ng-init="{{test(Form.input)}}"`.

Comment: The value is not wrong. You are just expecting it to be different, but that doesn't mean it is wrong. For that precise moment in time when you call `test(object)`, the value is what it is. If you could provide a plunker it would be easier to explain... Also, for the sake of simplicity, don't use `ng-init`.